# SQL query joining and grouping table

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008

Select table1.id, (table1.total_item-table2.requested) as items_left 
from table1, table2
where table2.year = 2015
group by table1.id

i am using SQL Server 2008..
Whats wrong with my code? it cannot be group in id number,

i want to sum all the individual table1.items in table1, and sum all the individual table2.requested in table 2 to
subtract the remaining items as I name it items_left, and group it by table1.id

something like this...

```
0.  id   items_left  year
1.   1    3        2015
2.   5    10       2015
3.   3    4        2015
```

this is the output of that code above...
there is a duplication of id and I cant group it to

```
0.  id  items_left
1.   1    1
2.   1    1
3.   1    2
4.   5    5
5.   3    2
6.   5    5
7.   3    2
```

i want an output like this.. please sir/ma'am help me..

something like this...

```
0. id items_left  year
1.   1    3       2015
2.   5    10      2015
3.   3    4       2015
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a "sum()" for the second field; also there is missing joining condition:

```
SELECT tab1.id, sum(tab1.total_item - ifnull(tab2.requested,0)) AS items_left
FROM tab1
LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.??
WHERE tab2.year = 2015
GROUP BY tab1.id
```